# Анимация на iOS7 не работает (на iOS6 все ОК)

Tags: objective-c, анимация, ios, ios7

С переходом на Xcode 5 и iOS7 SDK получил проблему при адаптации приложения под новую ось.
Типичный код анимации перемещаения отказывается работать. На устройствах со старой iOS все нормально, а на новой анимация не визуализируется:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
               self.ItemPhoto.alpha = 0;
            }
             completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 self.ItemPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(70, 20, self.ItemPhoto.frame.size.width,self.ItemPhoto.frame.size.height);

                 self.ItemPhoto.alpha=1;
             }];
```

По факту картинка меняет свою позицию, но без анимации

Comment: То есть у вас в течение 0.5 секунд не происходит переход в alpha 0 - я правильно понял? Действительно странно. Чисто навскидку - попробуйте соседний метод, который принимает опции: `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` - может быть там есть с чем поэкспериментировать? Не происходит ли в этот момент у вас там что-то параллельно?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich верно, анимация вызывается в touchesEnded. На Developer Forums нашел несколько подобных тем, решения пока не найдено, делаю вывод что это баг в iOS7, что печально:( [у многих проблема есть, у многих ее нет, у некоторых вообще появляется рандомно]

Comment: в качестве предположения - пробуйте поиграть с opaque, насколько я помню, если оно YES, то это сбивает настройки альфа и к тому же эппл любит попеределывать значение по умолчанию этого свойства в разных версиях своей операционки. Это уже было то ли при переходе с 3 на 4, то ли с 4 на 5

Comment: @aknew так проблема не с Alpha или Opaque, проблема именно с вызовом анимации, почему-то она не запускается (в другом месте анимация перемещения так же не работает)

Comment: Ещё вопрос: а вы пробовали внутри блока completion: делать NSLog(@"Animation is finished: %d", finished). Finished обращается в YES, когда анимация завершена, и в NO, когда что-то её прерывает. Гляньте.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich да, пробовал, в NSLog вообще ничего не выводится, будто Xcode просто игнорирует строки вызова анимации:(

Comment: Ещё вопрос: а если вы перед `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){` ставите NSLog(@"Before animation") - он выводится? Это тривиальный вопрос (я не подозреваю вас в глупости), просто нужно чётко знать, что выводится))

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich UPD, информация что в NSLog ничего не выводится оказалась ложной.  [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{ работает, в лог выводится и начало и конец, свойство alpha изменяется плавно, а перемещение все равно выполняется в момент. 
перемещение выполняю так: self.ItemPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(70, 20, self.ItemPhoto.frame.size.width, self.ItemPhoto.frame.size.height);

Поскольку отвечать на собственные вопросы не могу, напишу тут что проблема решилась удалением Xcode установленным из AppStore и уставновкой нового из образа скаченного с developer.apple.com

Comment: Вы похоже, значит, не понимаете суть того, как работает метод `+[UIView animateWithDuration...`. Всё что вы хотите чтобы изменилось в течение 5 секунду - должно быть помещено в блок animations:, а completion: - это блок, который всегда запускается __после того__, как 5 секунд прошли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
self.ItemPhoto.alpha = 0; // Откуда вы начинаете анимацию

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
    // А это куда вы хотите прийти в течение 0.5 секунд
    self.ItemPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(70, 20, self.ItemPhoto.frame.size.width, self.ItemPhoto.frame.size.height);             
    self.ItemPhoto.alpha=1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // А это запускается __после__ того, как 0.5 секунд прошли
}];
```

Надеюсь, я правильно понял логику вашей анимации.

Comment: а разве animateWithDuration:0.5 это не полсекунды?

Comment: Пардон, конечно 0.5. Обновлю ответ.